# Is the set of all 2x2 matrices a ring with zero divisors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let M be the set of all $2\times2$ matrices with real entries.

Under matrix addition and multiplication, is it a
ring with zero divisor?

Verify whether the above is true or false with
justification.

I did try this but am stuck at the very first step, so explain this.

Comment: Its with real entries. any 1

Comment: The advice is the same as when you asked a closely related question earlier: (1) check to see if it satisfies the axioms for a ring; (2) try to find a zero divisor.

Comment: You are asking lots of questions about your algebra studies. You don't show what you have tried, and you haven't accepted any answers. If you work on the problems yourself, tell us where you get stuck, and upvote and accept answers that help you will get much more help from this site.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1815802/is-a-certain-set-of-matrices-a-ring).

Answer (score 3):

The ring of all $2\times 2$ matrices with real coefficients has zero divisors.
For example:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}_.$$